# Having css issue with unordered lists

Tags: css, html-lists

Html markup

```
<ul>
 <li> <a href="...">parent</a>
   <ul><li> <a href="...">child</a> </li></ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

What I wanna do is to apply background only to parent li's.

```
ul li a{
    background:url(images/nav/divider.jpg) right bottom no-repeat;
}
```

This style applies to all li-s, not only parent.

How can I apply css rule only to parent li-s?

Comment: Very interesting HTML markup... Are you drunk? xD

Comment: Why are you selecting for `a` elements, if you want to style the (specific) `li` elements?

Comment: I don't get the "drunk HTML" comments. This example is perfectly valid markup. It even passes XHTML 1.0 Strict validation.

Comment: Actually the pre-edited HTML was quite wonky.

Comment: @Diodeus have you taken a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/rx8Mj/5/ link?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need the first child selector:

```
#foo > li{
    ...
}
```

This states "select the LI element after the #id, only".

*EDIT*
I should point out, you need to target the parent UL item with an ID or class.

*EDIT 2* I see your updated your HTML example.  Removed my nested HTML.

Comment: Did'nt work. I need this background only for parent li-s, nothing else. http://jsfiddle.net/rx8Mj/5/ please take a look at this. Hover on projects menu. You'll see what I'm talking about. Also, please simplify css a bit if it's not difficult for you. Thx in advance

Comment: http://content.screencast.com/users/TT13/folders/Jing/media/e967bb92-6086-4440-b06c-3d4cc417a3b9/2012-03-02_0027.png

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle that's similar to your screenshot.  http://jsfiddle.net/anMRJ/12/  The JSFiddle you gave just has too much going on and some of the images are not loading properly here at work to properly help you.  Hopefully this Fiddle will help.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your unusual HTML:

```
ul li.parent a {
    background:url(images/nav/divider.jpg) right bottom no-repeat;
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:15px;
}
```

Add your own value accordingly.

Comment: I need this background only for parent li-s, nothing else. http://jsfiddle.net/rx8Mj/5/ please take a look at this. Hover on projects menu. You'll see what I'm talking about. Also, please simplify css a bit if it's not difficult for you. Thx in advance

Comment: http://content.screencast.com/users/TT13/folders/Jing/media/e967bb92-6086-4440-b06c-3d4cc417a3b9/2012-03-02_0027.png

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic choices:

1. Use CSS to set the style for the `li` elements and then *override* those styles for child `li` elements, or
2. Specify an `id` for the parent, or *a* parent element and then more-specifically select

---

## 1

```
ul li {
    background-image: url(path.to/image.png);
}

ul li li {
    background-image: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4kjV4/).

## 2

```
<ul id="uniqueID">
    <li>first-level</li>
    <li>
         <ul>
             <li>Second-level</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and with the CSS:

```
#uniqueID > li {
    background-image: url(path.to/background-image.png);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4kjV4/1/)

It's worth noting, though, that many elements are, by default or with CSS-resets, styled to have transparent backgrounds. This means that you may have to over-ride the styles of the parent `li` elements, regardless:

```
#uniqueID > li {
    background-image: url(path.to/background-image.png);
}
li li {
     background-image: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4kjV4/3/)

Comment: Parent ul's class is `.menu`. So I used method 2. It still applies these rules to all childs. `.menu > li a{
    background:url(images/nav/divider.jpg) right bottom no-repeat;
}`

Comment: Method 1 is not for me. There are bunch of parent child's. I can't set rules for them one by one

Comment: I added a further demonstration, as I forgot about the default for (most) elements now being a transparent background. The final demo should illustrate.

Comment: There are bunch of parent child's. I can't set rules one by one for them. I need this background only for parent li-s, nothing else. http://jsfiddle.net/rx8Mj/5/ please take a look at this. Hover on projects menu. You'll see what I'm talking about. Also, please simplify css a bit if it's not difficult for you. Thx in advance

Comment: http://content.screencast.com/users/TT13/folders/Jing/media/e967bb92-6086-4440-b06c-3d4cc417a3b9/2012-03-02_0027.png